# Passing argument to WinSCP script in SSIS

Tags: ssis, arguments, winscp

I need an explanation how to pass arguments to WinSCP in SSIS Execute process task.

I want to download a latest file using SFTP on everyday basis.

I am able to connect to Remote Server using WinSCP in SSIS.

FTP Task steps:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis

I followed the steps as in:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting

My Problem is:
I want to pass parameter to my WinSCP Script.

My script has command `get "%1%"`.

Complete Script:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://usename:password@ftp.dummy.com
option transfer binary
cd /root
get "%1%" C:\Data\
close
exit
```

On my Execute Process Task editor, I am passing argument `*20120817*.xml` as below, but it is not working:

```
/script=scriptB.txt \*20120817\*.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `/parameter` switch:

```
/script=scriptB.txt /parameter *20120817*.xml
```

Refer to:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting